# Call a C function that returns a pointer from cython

Tags: cython, cythonize

I want to call a C `function`, declared in the header `function.h` from cython. The function returns a pointer to double and requires (double, double *, int) as input.

I'm working in the jupyter-notebook (on Ubuntu). The function definition is in the file `function.c`

The compiler returns the following error:

```
command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1.
```

The code is the following

```py
    %load_ext cython
    import Cython

    %%cython
    cdef extern from "function.c":
        pass
    cdef extern from "function.h":
        double* function(double, double *, int)

    import numpy as np

    def test(a, B): # B is a one-dim numpy array

        if not B.flags['C_CONTIGUOUS']:
            B = np.ascontiguousarray(B) 
        cdef double[::1] arr_memview = B

        cdef double[::1] x = <double[:arr_memview.shape[0]]>function(a, &arr_memview[0], arr_memview.shape[0])

        return np.asarray(x)
```

As you can see I am using the memview.
Can you please help me and tell me what is the correct sintax to use?
Thank you.

**EDIT**
The `double* function(double, double *, int)` can be any generic function with those arguments and return type. This is the c code I used:

function.h

```c
    #include<stdio.h>
    double* function(double a, double *B, int N);
```

function.c

```c
    #include "function.h"
    double* function(double a, double *B, int N){
      for (int i=0; i<N; ++i)
        printf("%f \n",a);
    return B;
}
```

I guess that the problem in my code is the cython syntax.

Comment: The gcc error is logged to terminal from which Jupiter was started. It tells you what is the problem - it is probably in function.h/c which we don’t see - please see [mcve].

Comment: @ead  I added the function.h/c.   The gcc message is quite hard to understand, but now its output can be reproduced by anyone.  I guess the problem is that I'm not familiar with the sintax. Thanks.

Comment: Well you definitely have a potential disaster in the making with the lack of include guards. And with memory management (who owns the pointer you return... in this case no-one, but is that always true). But as ead says, you should be trying to find the actual gcc error message, since this will be the informative bit.

Comment: @DavidW you are right. But for the moment I just want to understand how to pass a numpy array to the C function, and convert the output into another numpy array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case the actual output from GCC (from the terminal running Jupyter) is

```
fatal error: function.c: No such file or directory
618 | #include "function.c"
    |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

It would have helped if you'd have copied this as requested. You need to specify the include path so that it can find "function.c". You can add the current directory with

```
%%cython -I.
```

(although this may depend on your Jupyter base directory).

---

Your code potentially has a range of other issues. You should look up C include guards (their absence isn't causing you problems here, but may in other cases).

You should think quite hard about memory management and who owns the pointer that is returned. It needs to be consistent. Currently it's owned by `B`, but this is unlikely to always be true.

Comment: I put the .ipynb file in the same directory of function.h/c. I do not see that gcc output.
I did what you suggested but nothing changed.

Comment: The gcc output appears on the terminal that you're running jupyter from rather than in jupyter

Comment: Ok thanks. I guess the problem is how to give the correct instructions to the compiler.  
Now I'm studying how to compile it with a setup.py file. But I would prefer using only the jupyter notebook.

Comment: You could try substituting the full path to the directory with the files in: `%%cython -I/home/username/full/path`. Beyond that I don't know what to suggest - it works for me

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Before I did a stupid mistake when I tried to follow your indications. Now I tried again and it works. Your solution works perfectly. Tnx again.